# I can describe constant size message in protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

For example, I have next message:

```
Message Header {
    fixed32 messageType;
    fixed32 messageSize;
}
```

I can be sure that on any platform, on any language, Header will be seralized in constant size byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...ish, that *should* be predictable and fixed sized. The payload is fixed sized, and the header is varint encoded. There's a *slight* gotcha here is that the varint specification doesn't actually prohibit suboptimal encoding - it can *in theory* contain up to 9 extra bytes of zero padding with just the continuation bit set. But *in practice* this isn't a problem.

So: these are the same data interpreted as varint (value: 1):

Expected:

```
00000001
```

Suboptimal:

```
10000001 10000000 10000000 10000000 00000000
```

Very suboptimal:

```
10000001 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000 00000000
```

(the MSB of each byte is the continuation flag; the other 7 bits are payload, with the least significant group *first*; the maximum size of a varint here should be 10 bytes since only 64 bits are expected, but I wonder if any libraries don't explicitly check this!)

In reality: libraries use the first form.